# Determine value using array index with modulus operator

Tags: javascript, math, modulus

I hate maths. I could sit here for the next few hours trying to work this out but I'd hoped someone with half a brain might be able to help me with this basic math problem using modulus.

```
let bricks = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}]; // ...etc

for (var i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
  // determine colour using modulus
  bricks[i].colour = help;
}
```

I need the first brick to be red, the second brick to be green and the third brick to be blue. And then repeat that pattern for as many items as there are in the bricks array.

A somewhat embarrassing question, but any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to use modulus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take an array and the index with the modulo of the length of the color array.

```
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

for (var i = 0; i < bricks.length; i++) {
    bricks[i].colour = colors[i % colors.length];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` and take modulo of the length of the color array.

```js
let bricks = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}],
    colors = ['red','green','blue'],
    result = bricks.map(({id},i) => ({id, color : colors[i%colors.length]}));
console.log(result);
```